# Change Div using Li in html or javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display one div at a time and hide other .
Need the same effect like:http://jsfiddle.net/cqDES/1552/

```html
 <ul class="nav-sidebar">
  <li><a href="#">elem1</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">elem2</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">elem3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="div1">this is div 1</div>
<div id="div2">this is div 2</div>
<div id="div3">this is div 3</div>
```

Comment: Can you give more details about the question? It's not clear. :D

Comment: What is wrong with the code in the JSFiddle?

Comment: It is not working on my site

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want sliding effect use show()/hide()

```js
$(() => {
    $('div:not(#div0)').hide();
    $('.nav-sidebar li').click(function () {
      var index = $(this).index() + 1;
      $(`div:not(#div${index})`).hide();
      $(`#div${index}`).show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-sidebar">
  <li><a href="#">elem1</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">elem2</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">elem3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="div1">this is div 1</div>
<div id="div2">this is div 2</div>
<div id="div3">this is div 3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are asking for.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sz4f5kep/2/)

```js
$(function() {
    var panels = $('div').hide();
    var tabs = $('.nav-sidebar li');
    tabs.click(function(orgEvent) {
      let clickedTabIndex = tabs.index(orgEvent.currentTarget);
       panels.each((index, panel)=>{
          $(panel)[index === clickedTabIndex ? "slideDown" : "slideUp"]();
       });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-sidebar">
  <li> <a href="#">elem1</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">elem2</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">elem3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="div1">this is div 1</div>
<div id="div2">this is div 2</div>
<div id="div3">this is div 3</div>
```

Comment: Can you tell me that when I add this code to my website .html code.
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Then my whole website disappears.

Comment: If you are using it in html page, you can add this code within <head> tag. If the website disappears, please check for any errors in the console.

Comment: yes I am adding it in head , but when I run this whole code in a separate file then it runs good .When I add it in my already designed website then it displays none .Like whole website disappear.

Comment: Check for issues in console.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `show()/hide()` functions :

```js
$(function() {    
    $('.nav-sidebar li').click(function() {
        var index = $(this).index() + 1;
        $('div:not(#div' + index + ')').hide();
        $('#div' + index).show();
    });
});
```

```css
div[id^='div']
{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-sidebar">
  <li><a href="#">elem1</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">elem2</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">elem3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="div1">this is div 1</div>
<div id="div2">this is div 2</div>
<div id="div3">this is div 3</div>
```

[show function Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/show/)
[hide function Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Comment: exactly , your help and support is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell me that when I add this code to my website .html code Then why my whole website disappears

Comment: If the website disappears, please check for any errors in the console. https://balsamiq.com/support/faqs/browserconsole/

Comment: I have checked no error. it is may be because divs are used in script . Due to which divs in  my website disppears.